# NServiceBus - Notify User On Failure (After SLR)

Tags: nservicebus

I have a service that handles messages that persists data to an external system.  If (a.k.a. when) the writing of this data to the external system fails, or normal monitoring strategy will alert system admins of the failure.

I would like to also notify the user who submitted the message that there is a delay in processing their request.

Where/How is the best way to accomplish this scenario?  I've looked into the IManageMessageFailures, but it seems that will bypass the SLR functionality.

Comment: [bump] Does anyone have any suggestions for how to plug into this functionality?  I need to know somewhow when NServiceBus is done trying to process the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with NServiceBus version 5.1 now has the ability to use Reactive Extensions to observe when a message is sent to an error queue.  From there, you can log, email, or whatever best meets your needs.

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/subscribing-to-push-based-error-notifications

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and separate the two concerns?

Manage the 3rd party interaction in a saga, and if it fails, send a failure notification message (you can use timeout to cater for no proper reply).

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow... It doesn't feel like there are two concerns here.  There is one concern with copying the data.  If there is a problem with that copy, I want to tell the user (which sends a command to another notification service).  I'm just not sure how to know when NServiceBus is "done" trying with both FLR and SLR.

Comment: Sorry, i miss understood your use case, i thought you are saving the data in a remote system and using some kind of integration (http call or ftp), If you did, you could use a saga that will expect a reply form the message handler performing the integration and in case it fails (no reply) the saga would kick of the notification logic... does hat make sense?

Comment: It does make sense, but not quite what I'm after.  Does anyone have any thoughts about how to plug into an event or interface for when NSB is done with first and second level retries without implementing IManageMessageFailures?  I wouldn't mind implementing IManageMessageFailures, but from what I've read, this disables second level retries...